# Identity insert on linked server fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to use a stored procedure to copy a table from my test database to a linked server with the same ID's / Identity but I can't get it to work..
I've set the `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON` but it still complains about the ID column.

Here's my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST2PROD_CopyUIDataSServer]
AS Begin
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
-- First truncate target table
set @sql = 'EXEC [LINKEDSERVER].tempdb.sys.sp_sqlexec' + char(39)+ 'TRUNCATE Table [ProductManager].dbo.[UIData]' + char(39)+  ';'
---- SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON
set @sql = @sql + 'EXEC [LINKEDSERVER].tempdb.sys.sp_sqlexec' + char(39)+ 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ProductManager].[dbo].[UIData] ON' + char(39)+  ';'
---- INSERT UIDATA records from DB1 into linked server DB2
set @sql = @sql + 'WITH TestData as (SELECT * from ProductManager.dbo.UIData UID)' + NCHAR(13)+  'INSERT INTO   [LINKEDSERVER].[ProductManager].[dbo].[UIData]' + NCHAR(13) + 'select * from TestData;'
print @sql
exec (@sql) 
end
```

But when I execute the SP it gives me the following error:

> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server ....  could not INSERT INTO table "[LINKEDSERVER].[ProductManager].[dbo].[UIData]" because of column "Id". The user did not have permission to write to the column.

Linked server properties RPC and RPC out are set to true. I hope someboy can help me out here?

**UPDATE:** I decided to pull things apart, first I copy the data from the local server to the linked server in a `TEMP_TABLE` where I don't have to deal with `IDENTITY` issues.

Then I wrote a stored procedure on the linked / remote server, since I'm not using `SELECT *` but specify the column list. Chances are this will work from the local server in an SP too but I don't have the time or interest to check it out yet..

```
USE [ProductManager]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST2PROD_CopyBaseTables]
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @DestTable VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @DestPath VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SrceTable VARCHAR(255)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @columnList varchar(max)
DECLARE @err int

Begin TRY

declare @comma_delimited_list varchar(4000) 
--- FIRST TRY WITH ONE TABLE, EXTENDABLE...
set @comma_delimited_list = 'UIData' 

declare @cursor cursor 
set @cursor = cursor static for  
  select * from dbo.Split(@comma_delimited_list,',') a 

declare @naam varchar(50)
open @cursor 
while 1=1 begin 
  fetch next from @cursor into @DestTable
  if @@fetch_status <> 0 break 

    --Create tablenames
    SET @SrceTable = '[ProductManager].[dbo].TEMP_' + @DestTable
    SET @DestPath = '[ProductManager].[dbo].'+ @DestTable 
    print @srceTable;
    print @DestTable;

    --Truncate target table
    set @sql ='TRUNCATE TABLE '+ @DestPath + ';'

    --Insert statement needs column names
    set @columnList =''
    SELECT  @columnList = coalesce(@columnList + '[' + name + '],','') FROM sys.columns Where OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = @DestTable
    if RIGHT(RTRIM(@columnList),1) = ',' 
    begin
        SET @columnList = LEFT(@columnList, LEN(@columnList) - 1) 
    end

    --Transfer data from source table 2 destination
     set @sql = @sql + ' SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @DestPath + ' ON;' + ' INSERT INTO ' + @DestPath + '(' + @columnList + ') SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM ' + @SrceTable

    print @sql;

    exec (@sql)
end 
-- not strictly necessary w/ cursor variables since the will go out of scope like a normal var 
close @cursor 
deallocate @cursor 

End Try
Begin Catch
 declare @ErrorMsg nvarchar(MAX);
 select @ErrorMsg =  ERROR_MESSAGE();

SELECT @err = @@error IF @err <> 0 Return @err
end Catch
END
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`IDENTITY_INSERT` doesn't work with linked servers AFAIK, unless you execute dynamic SQL that includes the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` in the batch or have some code (Stored Proc for instance) on the remote server which does that for you.

The `IDENTITY_INSERT` is per-session (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)) and when you use the remote server this will probably be in a different session from your statement executed via `[LINKEDSERVER].tempdb.sys.sp_sqlexec`, which causes it to fail as you see it happening.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lucero but if I create an SP to turn identity on on the remote server and call it: set ATsql = ATsql + 'EXEC [37.230.100.75].ProductManager.dbo.TEST2PROD_IdentityOn;' I get the same error?

Regards,

Mike

Comment: @MikeDole, the whole code (setting identity-insert on, inserting the data, setting identity-insert off) would need to be in that one SP. E.g. you can feed single items to be inserted to the SP, or if you want to do set operations you need to pass in a TVP or have the linked server use the local server as linked server).

Comment: FYI. It does not magically work by wrapping it in dynamic sql.  You still get this error: The object name 'LINKED_SERVER.DestinationDatabase.dbo.DestinationTable' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Comment: The only way I could get it to work was to set IDENTITY_INSERT within a stored procedure on the destination linked server.

Comment: Indeed this is NOT supported in Linked Servers (this revelation led me to re-design some of my data tables and use uniqueidentifier instead of the IDENTITY column).

Answer (score 8):

You can **insert** an identity value into a table with an **identity column** on a **linked server** with the "SWITCH TO" trick.

If you haven't used the "SWITCH TO" trick to add and remove identity on a column, it's very quick, even on large tables!

Conceptually you simply create a new SCHEMA exactly like the table you are wanting to `INSERT` to *without* the identity defined.  Then switch the table to that SCHEMA and do your `INSERT`. Then switch back to the SCHEMA with the identity defined.
The sample below has been tested on a linked server in AZURE.
All the caveats of using "SWITCH TO" apply (indexes must be the same, drop and recreate foreign keys, etc)

To test, you can run the full script below on an Linked Azure SQL Server database.  You'll need to do a find/replace with `[LINKED_SERVER_NAME]` and `[DATABASE_NAME]`, replacing with your values.  On a non-Azure DB you may need to add "ON PRIMARY" to the table creations.

```
--Let's setup the example by creating a table with an IDENTITY column on the Linked Server
EXEC('
CREATE TABLE [DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](10) NULL
)
 '
) AT [LINKED_SERVER_NAME]

--INSERT some data into the table
INSERT INTO [LINKED_SERVER_NAME].[DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table] ([Name]) VALUES ('Travis')
INSERT INTO [LINKED_SERVER_NAME].[DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table] ([Name]) VALUES ('Mike')

-- Looks good
SELECT * FROM [LINKED_SERVER_NAME].[DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table]

GO


-- Create a TABLE with an identical schema, without the identity defined
EXEC('
CREATE TABLE [DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table_temp](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](10) NULL
)
 '
) AT [LINKED_SERVER_NAME]

--Now Use the "SWITCH TO" to move the data to the new table
EXEC('
 ALTER TABLE [DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table] SWITCH TO [DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table_temp]
  '
) AT [LINKED_SERVER_NAME]


--Drop the old table (It should now be empty, but you may want to verify that if you are unsure here)
EXEC('
 DROP TABLE [DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table]
 '
) AT [LINKED_SERVER_NAME] 

--Rename the new table back to the old table name
-- NOTE the lack of database and owner identifiers in the new name
-- NOTE the use of double single qoutes (ESCAPED single quotes)
EXEC('USE [DATABASE_NAME];
  EXEC sp_rename ''[DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].Example_Table_temp'',''Example_Table''
   '
) AT [LINKED_SERVER_NAME] 
  

  -- Now do your IDENTITY INSERTs !!!!

 INSERT INTO [LINKED_SERVER_NAME].[DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table] (ID,[Name]) VALUES (888,'Travis')
 INSERT INTO [LINKED_SERVER_NAME].[DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table] (ID,[Name]) VALUES (999,'Mike')

 --Verify they got put in
SELECT * FROM [LINKED_SERVER_NAME].[DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table] 

  
  --Now let's switch it back to our SCHEMA with an IDENTITY

  EXEC('
CREATE TABLE [DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table_temp](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](10) NULL
)

 ALTER TABLE [DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table] SWITCH TO [DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table_temp]

 DROP TABLE [DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table]

  EXEC sp_rename ''[DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].Example_Table_temp'',''Example_Table''
     '
) AT [LINKED_SERVER_NAME] 

--Data is still there
 SELECT * FROM [LINKED_SERVER_NAME].[DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table] 
 GO
 -- And note you can no longer INSERT the IDENTITY
 INSERT INTO [LINKED_SERVER_NAME].[DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[Example_Table] (ID,[Name]) VALUES (45,'Travis')
GO
```

Comment: Very useful. Note, I had to call `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[dbo].Example_Table_temp');` after calling `SWITCH TO`, to reset the Identity to the correct new value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute dynamic query Example :

```
exec [LINKSERVERNAME].[DATABASENAME].[SCHEMANAME].sp_executesql N'Your Query'
```

If any column set identity the you need to set `SET IDENTITY_INSERT TargetTable ON` and need to specified the column name. Example:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TargetTable ON;
INSERT INTO TargetTable(Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM SourceTable;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TargetTable OFF;
```

Comment: Won't this require a link from the remote database back to the source database so that the cross-database `INSERT ... SELECT` can work?

Comment: I like this idea. It would be like any dynamic SQL but the "Select Col1, Col2..." would be more like "VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6), etc".